# Angular component ignoring Bulma field css style

Tags: css, angular, bulma

When wrapping up a Bulma "field" styled element in a angular component the bottom margin is missing. The field class is added to the component through the `@HostBinding('class') classes = 'field'` directive, which is according to the browser working correctly.
I suspect it might be some problem with the `.field:not(:last-child)` selector, but I cannot figure out why.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cx1w49)

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Test
      <div class="control">
          <input type="text" class="input" />
      </div>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Test
      <div class="control">
          <input type="text" class="input" />
      </div>
  </label>
</div>

<app-input></app-input>
<app-input></app-input>
```

**input.component.html**

```
<label class="label">Test
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input" />
    </div>
</label>
```

**input.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class') classes = 'field'; 

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

This question somewhat builds upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51095987/14247618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input component hasn't set the display property.
So it's rendered as **display: inline**, which can't handle any margin's.

**First Solution:**

Add following snippet to your input.component.css:

```
:host { display: block; }
```

[Working example for method 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byysqa?file=src/app/input/input.component.css)

**Second Solution:**

You add **is-block** to css-classes of your input.component.ts

```
@HostBinding('class') classes = 'field is-block';
```

[Working example for method 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4s1kwc?file=src/app/input/input.component.ts)

Hope this helps, Happy Xmas, over and out ;-)